# How to open visual studio 2008 sln into visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, .net-framework-version, .net-3.5

My existing application is in visual studio 2008 (Framework version 3.5).

I want to open this application in visual studio 2013 but point the framework 3.5 only.

When i try to open the solution into visual studio 2013 then it asks for `one way upgrade`.

Can you guide me how can i open this solution into visual studio 2013 and keep pointed with fx 3.5 only.

Thank You

Comment: It wants to upgrade your project file, not your framework target.   Click Yes.

Comment: Yup it fixes by that way. I can mark that answer once you add one. thanks.